# SQLiteOpenHelper Application has opened too many files

Tags: android, sqliteopenhelper

I am facing a problem with my android app. I am running into this issue:

> SQLiteOpenHelper: Caused By : Application has opened too many files. Maximum of available file descriptors in one process is 1024 in default.
>
> (unknown error (code 2062): Could not open database)

What could be the possible cause of this issue? Thanks so much for ya help!

Comment: You are not closing your sqllite object after doing transaction. without the proper source it's not possible to detect the root cause.

Comment: ah! would you happen to know how to do this?

Comment: close sqllite database object. go to line showing error and close database object.

Comment: ah got it. Thanks so much! I will give this a shot.

Comment: Close the `DataSourceBase` class objects

Answer (score 4):

I ran across the same problem and I managed to solve it by closing the cursor by calling the following where I left it open:

> cursor.close();

I was creating a new object of the `Cursor` class inside a loop without closing it. While on small loop iterations it was working fine, after the data got bigger and the loop iterations too then I started seeing this problem.

Also as it is suggested in the comments of the questioner, make sure you close any object of the **SQlite database** as soon as you are finished.